# Understanding Feature Extraction and Feature Vectors in Image Processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I am working on a small project in Matlab just because of my interest in image processing and I have not studied a degree or a course related to image processing.

I want to understand a small concept about feature extraction and feature vectors. I have read some articles about that and in general I can understand that, but my question is:

For example, I want to extract some information from different objects of a binary image, the information is about length, width and distance between the objects. In one application I want to extract the features on which I want to apply some algorithms to compute width of all the objects and ignore the length and distance. Can we name this as feature extraction regarding the width? And storing them in different vectors as Feature Vectors?

It makes me think that, I might be complicating the simple things. Should I use some other terminologies for this instead of feature extraction and feature vectors?

Please suggest me if I am going in the right direction or not?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a question about programming, and hence off-topic. Please try asking over at https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion! I will post it there.

Answer (score 0):

Feature extraction is the process of computing numerical values on regions/objects/shapes/blobs detected in an image. [Sometimes the detection itself can be called extraction and the features need not be numbers.]

The feature values can indeed be stored in vectors, usually they fill a table. Sometimes they are structured in a more complicated way (such as a graph f.i.). Most of the time they are used for classification/recognition purposes or they can just be the output of the process on hand.

Comment: So from your comment I guess that I am going in the right direction, right?

Comment: @SAIP: what other direction could you go ?